# JQuery Settings the options for a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

Can anyone tell me how to set the options, such as scroll, for [this](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/#) plugin. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
$('.sample').uscrollbar({
    scroll: horizontal,
});
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.sample').uscrollbar({
    scroll: 'horizontal'
});
```

1. It's a string - so enclose it in quotes
2. Don't add `,` after the last object's property

Comment: okay so if I wanted multiple properties i put a `,` after each one except the last one?

Comment: @Richard: yep. The same for arrays: `[0, 1, 2]`